# Is uploading directly to BigQuery faster than uploading to Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm uploading a delimited file from my PC into BigQuery. Two ways I could do this:

- Upload to Cloud Storage, then load to BQ
- Upload to BQ directly

Is there a difference in upload time for each of these methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, goes through the same infrastructure either way.

The advantage of uploading directly to BQ is that it's simpler: only one service to interact with.

The advantage of uploading to GCS is that it gives you more flexibility. You can repeat your load job without re-uploading if the load job happens to fail (bad schema, etc), and you may have other reasons to want a copy of the data in GCS (loading into other systems, etc).

Comment: That's what I thought so, but I wanted to double-check.

Comment: If your dataset is large, the ability to repeat your load job without uploading data again makes the added step of loading to GCS first well worth it.